# R undefined columns selected

Tags: r, csv

I have some csv-files that I Import in R using the following Code line:

```
May_1795 = read.csv(paste("path", sep =";"), skip=9, Header =FALSE)
```

This works absolutely fine, but when calling a certain column then using:

```
May_1795[,4]
```

I get the error: undefined columns selected. Calling lines works fine, too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just check the `str(May_1795)`  Also you may need to specify the `sep` in `read.csv` as it is not `,` because by default it is `sep=","`  I don't understand `paste("path", sep=";")` Is it some kind of pseudocode

Comment: I just copied the Code line for importing the csv-file, but when I leave the paste-part, it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: The error is due to the fact that your file is not a data.frame with 4 columns. Check with `dim(may_179')'. You need to pass read.csv file name with the absolute path or the path relative to  your working directory (`getwd()'). I think you should really look at the documentation.

Comment: Also to make it faster and easier to read csv, you should use `data.table::fread`